# Issue using delegate method to poptoviewcontroller | Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following delegate method that I activate on dismiss of a .formsheet - when it dismisses I need to popToViewController - it appears `print("User Logged Out")` is also not printing, what is being done incorrectly? I am primarily instructed in how to do this using delegates if possible.

**View Controller 2**

```
var delegate: LogoutDelegate?

func logout() {
      print("Logout")
      self.delegate?.didLogout()
           dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
      })
}
```

**View Controller 1**

```
protocol LogoutDelegate {
    func didLogout() -> Void
}

 func didLogout() -> Void {
        print("User Logged Out")
          self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
 }
```

**Presenting ViewController2:**

```
let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Test") as! SettingsViewController
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Is `self.delegate` set? ie, no nil? You want to dimiss and pop at the same time?

Comment: I’m need to dismiss the view controller 2 and once fully dismissed, pop to the root view controller of 1

Comment: @Larme Do you know what I’m doing incorrectly? I appreciate the help

Comment: You didn't answer the most important part: is self.delegate nil ? Before if `self.delegate` is nil, then `self.delegate?.didLogout()` won't call `didLogout()`... So is it nil? If so why? Where did you supposed set it?

Comment: I’m not sure where it is supposed to be set, the button that triggers this logout delegate is only one that uses it, it should not be nile, where would it normally be set?

Comment: When you create/initialize ViewController2 ? How is shown ViewController2 ?

Comment: I am currently doing the following: `class ViewController1: UIViewController, LogoutDelegate {`

Comment: No. That's just how id declared `ViewController1`. I'm asking "How is shown ViewController2 ? "? By code? By segue? How?

Comment: Apologies, I’m not currently doing anything more in ViewController then what is shown in the post, can you please show how the delegate can be set?

Comment: Wait. Are you saying that ViewController2 appears from nowhere? It appears by itself? You didn't do anything to do so? Is that magic?

Comment: Please see the updated post, not quite magic

Comment: That code is inside ViewController1? That where you should do `controller2.delegate = self` then...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your ViewController2 is `SettingsViewController`, when you are preparing to present ViewController2, you need to set its delegate to your current viewController `viewController1`.

Sth like this:

```
    let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Test") as! SettingsViewController
    controller.delegate = self
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
    navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .formSheet
    self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Again, I'm assuming this code is in your VC1, so in this case self is your VC1.